# VHDL latch for Xilinx Spartan 3E

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, spartan, ise

I am coding a display control for the Spartan 3E. It has 8 LEDs. When the ALU's state signal (from other block) is "00" the MSBs and LSBs are time-multiplexed for one second each byte. When state is not "00" then a LED is rotated to right every 125 ms. The FPGA clock is 100 MHz. I have the following code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity display_control is

  port (
    clk        : in  std_logic;
    rst        : in  std_logic;
    state      : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    MSB_result : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    LSB_result : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    leds       : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));

end display_control;

architecture rtl of display_control is
  signal en_1Hz                    : std_logic; 
  signal en_8Hz                    : std_logic; 
  signal cnt0_next, cnt0_reg       : integer;
  signal cnt1_next, cnt1_reg       : integer;
  signal ror_next, ror_reg, x      : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  signal muxctrl_reg, muxctrl_next : std_logic;

  constant PRESCALER0_DIV_FACTOR : integer := 100;  --000000;  -- 100M = (100MHz/0.5MHz)
  constant PRESCALER1_DIV_FACTOR : integer := 12;  --500000;  -- 12.5M = (100MHz/8MHz)

begin

  -- registers
  process (clk, rst, en_8Hz, en_1Hz)
  begin
    if rst = '1' then
      cnt0_reg    <= 0;
      cnt1_reg    <= 0;
      muxctrl_reg <= '0';
      ror_reg     <= (others => '0');
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
      cnt0_reg <= cnt0_next;
      cnt1_reg <= cnt1_next;
      if en_1Hz = '1' then
        muxctrl_reg <= muxctrl_next;
      end if;
      if en_8Hz = '1' then
        ror_reg <= ror_next;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  -- register's next state
  cnt0_next    <= cnt0_reg +1 when cnt0_reg /= PRESCALER0_DIV_FACTOR -1 else 0;
  cnt1_next    <= cnt1_reg +1 when cnt1_reg /= PRESCALER1_DIV_FACTOR -1 else 0;
  muxctrl_next <= not muxctrl_reg;
  ror_next     <= ror_reg(0) & ror_reg(6 downto 0);
  -- prescalers output
  en_1Hz       <= '1'         when cnt0_reg = PRESCALER0_DIV_FACTOR -1  else '0';
  en_8Hz       <= '1'         when cnt1_reg = PRESCALER1_DIV_FACTOR -1  else '0';

  -- output logic
  x <= LSB_result when  muxctrl_reg = '0' else MSB_result;
  leds <= x when state = "00" else ror_reg;

end rtl;
```

But when I synthesize the code I obtain the following warnings:

```
WARNING:Xst:3002 - This design contains one or more registers/latches that are directly
   incompatible with the Spartan6 architecture. The two primary causes of this is
   either a register or latch described with both an asynchronous set and
   asynchronous reset, or a register or latch described with an asynchronous
   set or reset which however has an initialization value of the opposite 
   polarity (i.e. asynchronous reset with an initialization value of 1).
```

and

```
WARNING:Xst:1426 - The value init of the FF/Latch cnt0_reg_31_LD hinder the constant cleaning in the block display_control.
   You should achieve better results by setting this init to 0.
```

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: You should not combine clocked and combinatorial process in one. Even thought the tool accept this, it is not the right coding style. You should split your process into 2 separate process, one with (clk, rst) in the sensitivity list, and the second one with (en_8Hz, en_1Hz) in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the second warning correctly, ISE would like you to give an explicit start value to some of your signals:

```
signal cnt0_next, cnt0_reg : integer := 0;
signal cnt1_next, cnt1_reg : integer := 0;
```